# difference between LED TVs and monitors

Tags: display, tv

Some people recommend not to watch TV from a close distance yet we all are stuck to our monitors without any issues. I wonder if computer monitors have some special eye protection mechanisms not built into TVs(both LED monitors and TVs). Or is this just a difference in terminology?

Comment: Back when they used crt's, it was not good to sit close due to radiation, I don't see this as a problem anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Some people recommend not to watch TV from a close distance**

There is no real problem in 2020. There is no special eye protection needed. There is no significant difference in terminology.

---

According to [Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/earth-talk-tv-eyesight/)

> Luckily for many of us and our kids, sitting “too” close to the TV isn’t known to cause any human health issues. This myth prevails because back in the 1960s General Electric sold some new-fangled color TV sets that emitted excessive amounts of radiation—as much as 100,000 times more than federal health officials considered safe. GE quickly recalled and repaired the faulty TVs, but the stigma lingers to this day.
>
> Dr. Lee Duffner of the American Academy of Ophthalmology isn’t concerned, maintaining that watching television screens—close-up or otherwise—“won’t cause any physical damage to your eyes.” He adds, however, that a lot of TV watching can surely cause eye strain and fatigue, particularly for those sitting very close and/or watching from odd angles. But there is an easy cure for eye strain and fatigue: turning off the TV and getting some rest. With a good night’s sleep, tired eyes should quickly return to normal.

See also

- [Report from California newspaper 1967](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/?a=d&d=DS19670609.2.49&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN--------1)

> The General Electric Company is recalling 90,000 color television receivers sold since last June because X-radiation given off by the sets is apparently in excess of desirable levels, according to Rodale’s Health Bulletin. G.E. will modify the sets by replacing the regulator tube and adjusting the power supply. Other manufacturers have indicated more problems with color tubes than black-and-white because of the high voltage involved. The Public Health Service’s
> advice to color television viewers is to avoid sitting directly under the set. The National Center for Radiological Health in Rockville, Md., urges anyone owning one of the G.E. sets to get in touch with his repairman and have it fixed. A person who sits directly under such a set for a cumulative total of 40 hours might receive enough radiation to any exposed portion of his body to make the skin red and somewhat painful. Sets resting directly on the floor would probably pose no radiation problem at all, a spokesman for the Center said. In a statement released May 18, G.E. said that the radiation in the sets was “directed toward the floor and not toward the viewer.”

---

TV screens are designed to be viewed from further away than we view personal computer monitors.

Other than this there is no health related issue other than spending too long looking at something from an odd angle.